# Detect pulling listview and refresh

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I even don't know, what to write in title bar.

I want my app to implement this feature:

[image]

For those, who don't understand what I'm talking about:

I have a `LitsView`. I want to load some more data, if the user pulls the `ListView` "out of it boundaries".

Maybe there's some tutorial for this?

Comment: google => pull to refresh android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [that library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). It's the best pull-to-refresh library on Android.

Answer (score 1):

There are many open source library's to implement this feature as Romain suggested . Listing down few open source project links and tutorial on how to implement it.

http://www.recursiveawesome.com/blog/2011/04/29/implementing-pull-to-refresh-in-your-android-app/

https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView